# EJS - I Have an error with the res.render of a request query object

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs, template-engine

I have two files :

1. `App.js` with the following code :

```
    app.get('/contact', function(req, res, next) {
        res.render('contact.ejs', { qs: req.query });
    });
```

2. That is a Views `contact.ejs` with the sample following code to invoke the **ejs**
   functionalities:

```
   <p> <%= qs %> </p>
```

When i run the app with node app.js and launch at localhost:4040/contact?dept=lol&people=90
i meet this error :

> SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list in
>   C:\Users\manue\Desktop\NodeJsTutorial\views\contact.ejs while
>   compiling ejs

But I really don't know where I'm mistaking.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print entire query object you can do

```
app.get('/contact', function(req, res, next) {
        res.render('contact.ejs', { qs: JSON.stringify(req.query)});
    });
```

Comment: Thank u for your answers,
I'll tried ur solution but the error still to persist.